# Retrieve the row value when the mouse hover on the rowbody of the row on the grid extjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, grid

i want to retrieve the data of the row if the mouse hover on the "row-body".
i tried to use "row body select" and "enter mouse" but that do not retrieve the row data.

Comment: Can you post code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is a listener for that called "itemmouseenter".

Here is an example:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    listeners: {
        itemmouseenter: function(this, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
            // record is holding your data of the row
            alert(record.get('yourcolumnindex'));
        }
    }
}
```